# Spark Memory Issue - "There is no enough memory to build hash map"

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, heap-memory

I am doing a left join between two tables - the left table(let's say A) has 1.4 billion records with size estimator giving it a size of 17GB, the right table(B) has 100 million records - with an approx size of 1.3GB.

The output of the above-joined dataframe has 120 million records (there are filters in place which brought down the record number after the left join). The output dataframe is getting used twice - so I cached it.

Now, when I ran the job as it is - took 1 hour and 40 minutes to run.

So to reduce the processing time, I was trying to implement broadcast join on the first left join between A and B. Now here comes the issue.

I am using the below configurations parameters -

```
"spark.ui.threadDumpsEnabled" = "true"
"spark.memory.storageFraction" = "0.5"
"spark.sql.shuffle.partitions" = "400"
"spark.driver.maxResultSize" = "8G"
"spark.sql.broadcastTimeout" = "36000"
"spark.driver.memory" = "30G"
"spark.executor.memory" = "15G"
"spark.executor.cores" = "4"
"spark.executor.instances" = "3"
"spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max" = "1500m"
"spark.driver.cores" = "4"
"spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled" = "false"
"spark.serializer" = "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer"
"spark.executor.defaultJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC -Xss100M -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+G1SummarizeConcMark -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent" = "45"
"spark.driver.defaultJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC -Xss100M -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+G1SummarizeConcMark -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent" = "45"
```

All these parameters came into the picture one after another as I was encountering numerous memory issues.

`"spark.sql.broadcastTimeout" = "36000"`
-- this came because I was facing below error

```
[org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec.logError@91] - Could not execute broadcast in 300 secs.
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [300 seconds]
```

`"spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max" = "1500m"` - this came because -

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Kryo serialization failed: Buffer overflow. Available: 0, required: 4658915. To avoid this, increase spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max value
```

I also faced these errors -

```
b) java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
c) java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

But, currently, I am facing this issue which is completely new to me and I could not find a solution -

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: There is no enough memory to build hash map
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.UnsafeHashedRelation$.apply(HashedRelation.scala:314)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.HashedRelation$.apply(HashedRelation.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.HashedRelationBroadcastMode.transform(HashedRelation.scala:857)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.HashedRelationBroadcastMode.transform(HashedRelation.scala:845)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec$$anonfun$relationFuture$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec$$anonfun$relationFuture$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec$$anonfun$relationFuture$1.apply(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec$$anonfun$relationFuture$1.apply(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:75)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
```

Thinking it is coming because I am not using any `action` until the last step of the execution, I tried to break the lineage by using intermediate `action` like `count`

But the issue still persists, I also tried to increase the driver memory to a great extent, but no luck.

## EDITS

This is the first query I was talking about

```
val a = spark.sql("""
select 
/*+ BROADCAST(schema.table2) */
visit_date, 
v4.visid, 
visit_num,
device_family,
operating_system,
'test' AS traffic_grouping,
'test2'Junk_Filter,
'test3' visit_start_evar26,
visit_start_pagename,
visit_start_url,
referrer_domain,
session_duration,
isp_domain,
pages_visited,
qbo_sui_click,
qbo_sui_trial_click,
qbo_sui_buy_click,
qbse_sui_click,
qbse_sui_trial_click,
qbse_sui_buy_click,
qbse_customer_flag,
qbo_customer_flag,
case when s.ivid is not null then 1 else 0 end as segment_qbo
from schema.table2 v4
left join schema.table2 s 
    on v4.ivid = s.ivid and v4.visit_date > s.qbo_signup_date and source = 'check'
WHERE visit_date >= '2020-07-14'
and country in ('Australia','Australia')
and  ((ipd_flag = 0
    AND sbbg_flag = 0)
  or lower(visit_start_evar26) like ('%buy%'))
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23
""")
```

here I have done a broadcast join.

[image]

If anyone has any leads, it would really be a great help, thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show us your code and explain what you do or want to do with the output?

Comment: You talk about broadcast.. broadcasting what data?

Comment: We have an application, and the data are related to people visiting our application, like timestamp, location, device using which they have connected, the pages that they have visited, whether they have subscribed to our channel, so on and so forth, these data are confidential otherwise I would have shared, each table has 100+ columns in it. Regarding code part, it is very simpler and straight forward left join and couple of filters, I am really sorry if this is not sufficient enough :)

Comment: Code always helps... ;) Have you tried to not use the heap? which v of Spark are you using?

Comment: Hello @jgp, added the first query - it had a bunch of case(when then) which I removed. And I am using spark 2.4

Comment: What do you want to do with the 120B rows output? Write to a file ? My point was: do you really need to cache it / collect it ?

Comment: so I will be using that dataframe with 120M rows in 2 other queries, and the final output will be written to S3

Comment: added the spark plan